# HTML 5 Boilerplate not working on PHP server?

Tags: php, apache, html5boilerplate

Ok, so I'll admit upfront: I don't know exactly what I'm doing. I've never used H5BP before and I'm not a developer, I'm a designer.

I downloaded H5BP locally. I am not running Apache locally. I set up my site in my HTML editor. It works locally. I uploaded it to my server which is running an existing Apache PHP site. I get this error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to     complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

Is there something special I need to do to make this work on an Apache server running PHP?

Comment: Read the last line of the material you quoted.

Comment: ***"More information about this error may be available in the server error log."*** Check your error log.

Comment: except that I don't know what a log file is. Like I said in the first line "I don't exactly know what I'm doing"

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly pretty but meh...

One solution would be to delete .htaccess and write one yourself if you really need it.

It should really work without that file. But I think you should check your log file to see what exactly triggers the error.